# я не могу понять как работает input() с функцией def в питоне

Tags: python, функции

данный код должен принимать text и word в качестве входящих данных и передает их в функцию с именем search(). Функция  search() должна вернуть "Word Found" если слово представлено в тексте или "Word not found" если не представлено в тексте.

```
#сдесь должна быть функция search(), но я так и не понял что делать.

text = input()
word = input()

print(search(text,word))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели получить что-то вроде этого?

```
import re
def search_word(word,text):
    if re.search(word,text) == None:
        return 'Word Not Found'
    else:
        return 'Word Found'

word = 'go'    #или word = input()
text = 'oh here we go again' #или text = input()

print(search_word(word,text))
```

Comment: Именно это он и хотел получить, самому не тратить время и постараться самостоятельно хоть что-то написать, а просто дайте готовое все.

Comment: Согласен, в интернете полно информации..
И если не понял как ходить, не стоит начинать бежать

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так решить это задание:

```
text = input("Введите текст: ")
word = input("Введите искомое слово: ")


def search(text, word):
    if (word in text):
        return "Word Found"
    return "Word not found"


print(search(text, word))
```